# Wordpress block editor embeds not working in theme (single.php)

Tags: block-editor, get-posts, single, embed, youtube

I am trying to embed '[spotify](https://wordpress.org/support/article/spotify-embed/)' and '[youtube](https://wordpress.org/support/article/youtube-embed/)' services in the block editor. When added from the admin, they are displayed fine in the block editor, but when the post content is printed from the theme (single.php), only the respective urls are printed. The rendered HTML looks like:

For Spotify:

```
<figure class="wp-block-embed is-type-rich is-provider-spotify wp-block-embed-spotify wp-embed-aspect-21-9 wp-has-aspect-ratio"><div class="wp-block-embed__wrapper">
https://open.spotify.com/episode/xxxxxx&amp;dl_branch=1
</div></figure>
```

For Youtube:

```
<figure class="wp-block-embed is-type-video is-provider-youtube wp-block-embed-youtube wp-embed-aspect-4-3 wp-has-aspect-ratio"><div class="wp-block-embed__wrapper">
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xxxxxx
</div></figure>
```

In single.php, I'm obtaining the post content through [get_posts()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_posts/) and printing the content with:

```
<?php echo do_shortcode($tpostObj->content); ?>
```

The other contents like texts, images etc are working fine. If the embeds are done with custom HTML *iframe*, they are working.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That would be because they're using oEmbed, not a shortcode.

You should use the function `the_content()` to render the content of a post, as it applies all the things required to make embeds, shortcodes, etc work properly. If for some reason that's not an option, you can apply the content filter.

```
<?php echo apply_filters( 'the_content', $tpostObj->content ); ?>
```

Comment: Thank you. apply_filters( 'the_content', $tpostObj->content ); is producing an empty string

Comment: A plugin was messing up with 'the_content' filter. Removing it gets the filter to work properly. Can you please add this point in the answer (that there is a need to check if any plugin/theme file messing up with the 'the_content' filter)?
It can be traced by searching the occurrences of 'the_content' string within the theme or the plugins directory and trace the subsequent 'add_filter' hook.